# Procedural NavigationPolygon for a platformer in Godot 4

Tags: procedural-generation, platformer, navmesh, godot-4

I'm trying to make navigation possible for npcs in a 2D platformer.

The game generates chunks with random platforms as the player ascends, so I also need to implement the navigation procedurally.

Each chunk is a square of 192x192px, so first I create a square shaped outline (clockwise) that conforms all the chunk:

```
    var new_2d_region_rid: RID = NavigationServer2D.region_create()
    var default_2d_map_rid: RID = get_world_2d().get_navigation_map()
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_map(new_2d_region_rid, default_2d_map_rid)

    var chunk_outline := PackedVector2Array([
        Vector2(0.0, current_chunk_row),
        Vector2(CHUNK_SIZE.x, current_chunk_row),
        Vector2(CHUNK_SIZE.x, current_chunk_row + CHUNK_SIZE.y),
        Vector2(0.0, current_chunk_row + CHUNK_SIZE.y),
    ])
```

Then, my intention is to clip or substract the platforms (obstacles) from that outline. Platforms for the new chunk are stored in an `Array[PackedVector2Array]` clockwise:

```
    var ccw_outlines: Array[PackedVector2Array] = []
    for platform in platforms_of_new_chunk:
        var clipped_outlines := Geometry2D.clip_polygons(chunk_outline, platform)
        # save the holes for later
        for clipped_outline in clipped_outlines:
            # holes are CCW from Geometry2D.clip_polygons
            if not Geometry2D.is_polygon_clockwise(clipped_outline):
                ccw_outlines.push_back(clipped_outline)
```

Lastly I create the [`NavigationPolygon`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_navigationpolygon.html#class-navigationpolygon-method-add-polygon):

```
    var new_navigation_polygon := NavigationPolygon.new()
    new_navigation_polygon.add_outline(chunk_outline) # the big one covering the whole chunk
    for outline in ccw_outlines:
        outline.reverse() # I reverse this to make them CW, b/c error msg says so
        new_navigation_polygon.add_outline(outline)
    new_navigation_polygon.make_polygons_from_outlines()
    
    NavigationServer2D.region_set_navigation_polygon(new_2d_region_rid, new_navigation_polygon)
```

This gives me 2 error messages and obviously *no platform avoiding navigation*:

> E 0:00:00:0962   sync: Navigation map synchronization error. Attempted
> to merge a navigation mesh polygon edge with another already-merged
> edge. This is usually caused by crossing edges, overlapping polygons,
> or a mismatch of the NavigationMesh / NavigationPolygon baked
> 'cell_size' and navigation map 'cell_size'.   <C++ Source>
> modules/navigation/nav_map.cpp:845 @ sync()

And (emphasis mine):

> E 0:00:12:0220   level.gd:102 @ generate_navigation_region():
> NavigationPolygon: Convex partition failed! Failed to convert outlines
> to a valid NavigationMesh. NavigationPolygon outlines can not overlap
> vertices or edges inside same outline or with other outlines or have
> any intersections. **Add the outmost and largest outline first. To add
> holes inside this outline add the smaller outlines with same winding
> order.**   <C++ Source>   scene/resources/navigation_polygon.cpp:296 @
> make_polygons_from_outlines()     level.gd:102 @
> generate_navigation_region()
> level.gd:63 @ generate_chunks()
> level.gd:189 @ _on_area_2d_body_entered()

I think I'm doing it as the error suggests. What could be wrong? Or maybe there's another way to achieve what I want.